# Multi-page website localstorage get and set

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am creating a multi page website and on the opening page I have a div that has two buttons inside it. When clicked these buttons change the theme. I have it so when on the first page you tap dark for example it changes the theme to dark. What i want next is to have it so when you go to the next page that theme carries over. I ALSO want it so if you change the theme on the 2nd page then click home that carries back over to the home page or the third page etc

what is happening now is i successfully change the theme on the first page but when i go to the 2nd page the div asking what theme you want is back

Here is my code

```js
var themes = {
  default : "assets/grey.jpg",
  dark    : "assets/dark.jpg",
  light   : "assets/background.jpg"
};




var background_image = localStorage.getItem("background-image")


if (background_image !== "assets/grey.jpg"){
  $('.popups').css('display', 'block')
} else if(background_image === "assets/dark.jpg" || background_image === "assets/background.jpg"){
  $('.popups').css('display', 'none')
}




$("#dark, #light, #default").click(function(){

    $("body").css( "background-image" , "url("+ themes[this.id] +")" );
    $(".popups").toggle();
    localStorage.setItem("background-image",  themes[this.id]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>United Photographers Initiative</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>
<body>

  <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href ="#" class="navbar-brand">U.P.I.</a>
      <img src="assets/camera.png" class="pull-left">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Options<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li id=default><a  href="#">Change Theme</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container">



<div class="popups">
  <p>
    Select your theme:<br><br>
    <button id="dark">DARK</button>
    <button id="light">LIGHT</button>
  </p>
</div>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to the <span class="h1Color">U</span>nited <span class="h1Color">P</span>hotographers <span class="h1Color">I</span>nitiative</h1>
    <p>This free community for experienced photographers to give back to those who are just starting out, as well as those photographers who are just starting out or are finding it hard to find new locations to shoot when at home or traveling.</p>




      <a href="login.html"<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ">Enter Site</button></a>


  </div>
</div>




<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-left">
      Site built by Self Aware Machines
    </p>

<p>
  <div class="input-group col-lg-3 pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Site"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
    </span>

  </div>
</p>

  </div>
</div>







<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>

// $("body").css( "background-image" , "url("+ localStorage.getItem("background-image") +")" );



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify? From what I can understand, I think your problem is when you go back, the theme is the same. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What happens now is that when i choose a theme from the index page and then go to the 2nd page the theme is back to the default and the div that has the question as to which theme you would like is back............Also if on the 2nd page and you choose a theme and then hit the home button the same div with the question pops up.........it is like the localstorage get and set are not working

Comment: how you are storing which theme is set to entire website

Comment: Im using localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me walk you through your code:

```
var themes = {
  default : "assets/grey.jpg",
  dark    : "assets/dark.jpg",
  light   : "assets/background.jpg"
};




var background_image = localStorage.getItem("background-image")
```

Stop! First here you are assuming that the localStorage is set, if it's not localStorage will return `null` Try this instead:

```
var background_image;
if(localStorage.getItem("background-image") {
   background_image = localStorage.getItem("background-image")
} else {
   background_image = themes.defualt
}
```

Ok, keep going:

```
if (background_image !== "assets/grey.jpg"){
  $('.popups').css('display', 'block')
} else if(background_image === "assets/dark.jpg" || background_image === "assets/background.jpg"){
  $('.popups').css('display', 'none')
}
```

Here, you are saying if the background image is the defualt, then show the popups, otherwise don't show them. However, it would be better to just implement this into our if condition up there, so:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("background-image")) {
   background_image = localStorage.getItem("background-image")
} else {
   background_image = themes.defualt
   $('.popups').css('display', 'block')
}
```

However to do this you must set the `.popups` to `display: none` by defualt, continue:

```
$("#dark, #light, #default").click(function(){

    $("body").css( "background-image" , "url("+ themes[this.id] +")" );
    $(".popups").toggle();
    localStorage.setItem("background-image",  themes[this.id]);
});
```

One last thing: `$(".popups").toggle()` should be `$(".popups").hide()` to make sure that your are hiding it.

Hope I could help!

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I forgot to close the if()

Comment: I fixed that....when i copied and pasted it for some reason my IDE messed up....BUT the same issue happens where the 2nd page doesnt acknowledge the theme change   I do like how you explained it tho!!!!

Comment: Check your localStorage to see if it is set, I'll try to draft up a demo for you

Comment: I tried to do a jsfiddle but i can't figure out how to make a multi page fiddle

Comment: when i click the link it says this:  No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Well, I don't have anything better to do on a saturday night :D Your welcome

Answer (score 0):

`background_image !== "assets/grey.jpg"`

maybe change it to

`background_image === "assets/grey.jpg"`

Even better just:

```
if(background_image === "assets/dark.jpg" || background_image === "assets/background.jpg"){
  $('.popups').hide() // the same as setting display: none
}
```

No need to set div display: block since it's block by default.

Comment: I didn't know that about .hide() = display: none thank you for that

Comment: Sorry meant to add this on the same comment, the above code didn't work :/